# Specific ten digit number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

I'm trying to solve this little problem. So far no luck. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance :)

What is the ten digit number such that the i-th digit is the number of i's in the number ( 0<= i <= 9) (the 0th position is number of zeros in the number, the 1st position is number of ones in the number,…)?

Comment: 6210001000 works.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution:
$$6210001000$$
$$(0123456789)$$

Comment: I think the problem wants it the other way around.

Comment: It looks like the request was in the opposite order, 6210001000, which avoids leading zeros.

Comment: Sloan (http://oeis.org/A108551) claims this solution is unique.  Is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: A more general version of this question came up recently. Put 6210001000 in the search box to see it.